# How to change the position of a grid item left and right in a map() function

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a page containing a "Timeline" element from Material Ui, with an "alternate" alignment. So I have a "TimeLineContent" containing several elements: Paper, Typography (For title and description) and an image.

I want to make the text always towards the center of the timeline. That is to say, one time the text is to the left, another to the right ...

Here an example of my problem :
[image]

- The first TimelineContent is good (Text is to the left)
- The second one is not good (Text is not to the right)

I could have used a flex-direction : reverse-row but I have several TimelineContent like this which are created with a .map()

Here the code I have right now :

```js
<Timeline align="alternate">
           {result.map((index) => {
                return (
                        <TimelineItem className={classes.timelineStyle}>

                            <TimelineOppositeContent>
                                <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
                                    {index.sif_date}
                                </Typography>
                            </TimelineOppositeContent>

                                <TimelineSeparator>
                                    <TimelineDot className={classes.dot}>
                                        <LaptopMacIcon/>
                                    </TimelineDot>
                                <TimelineConnector />
                                </TimelineSeparator>

                            <TimelineContent>
                                <Paper elevation={3} className={classes.paper}>
                                    
                                    <Grid style={{display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'nowrap'}}>
                                        <Grid item>
                                            <Typography variant="h6" component="h1">
                                                {index.sif_titre}
                                            </Typography>
                                            <Typography style={{fontSize: 'smaller'}}>
                                                {index.sif_msg}
                                            </Typography>
                                        </Grid>

                                        <Grid item>
                                            <Zoom overlayBgColorStart='rgba(73, 80, 87, 67)' overlayBgColorEnd='rgba(73, 80, 87, 67)' zoomMargin={100}>
                                                <img src={index.sif_image} alt={index.sif_image} className={classes.img} style={{maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: 200}}/>
                                            </Zoom>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>

                                </Paper>
                            </TimelineContent>

                        </TimelineItem>
                )
                })
            }
        </Timeline>
```

```css
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    padding: '6px 16px',
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white !important',
    display: 'flex'
  },
  secondaryTail: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
  img : {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
  dot : {
      backgroundColor: '#ef9700'
  },
  timelineStyle: {
      padding: '0px 300px !important'
  }
}));
```

EDIT :

Full code of my page :

```js
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import Timeline from '@material-ui/lab/Timeline';
import TimelineItem from '@material-ui/lab/TimelineItem';
import TimelineSeparator from '@material-ui/lab/TimelineSeparator';
import TimelineConnector from '@material-ui/lab/TimelineConnector';
import TimelineContent from '@material-ui/lab/TimelineContent';
import TimelineOppositeContent from '@material-ui/lab/TimelineOppositeContent';
import TimelineDot from '@material-ui/lab/TimelineDot';
import {Grid} from "@material-ui/core";

import LaptopMacIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LaptopMac';

import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {data} from './data.json';
import axios from 'axios';

import Zoom from 'react-medium-image-zoom';
import 'react-medium-image-zoom/dist/styles.css';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    padding: '6px 16px',
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white !important',
    display: 'flex'
  },
  secondaryTail: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
  img : {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
  dot : {
      backgroundColor: '#ef9700'
  },
  timelineStyle: {
      padding: '0px 300px !important'
  },
  Grid: {
    display: 'flex', 
    flexWrap: 'nowrap',
    flexDirection: 'row',
        '&:nth-child(2n+1)': {
        flexDirection: 'row-reverse',
    }
  }
}));


const index = () =>{
    const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get('/api/timeLine_siinfra').then((response) => {
          setResult(response.data)        
        });
    }, []);

    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        
        <Timeline align="alternate">
           {result.map((index) => {
                return (
                        <TimelineItem className={classes.timelineStyle}>

                            <TimelineOppositeContent>
                                <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
                                    {index.sif_date}
                                </Typography>
                            </TimelineOppositeContent>

                                <TimelineSeparator>
                                    <TimelineDot className={classes.dot}>
                                        <LaptopMacIcon/>
                                    </TimelineDot>
                                <TimelineConnector />
                                </TimelineSeparator>

                            <TimelineContent>
                                <Paper elevation={3} className={classes.paper}>

                                    <Grid container className={classes.Grid}>
                                        <Grid item>
                                            <Typography variant="h6" component="h1">
                                                {index.sif_titre}
                                            </Typography>
                                            <Typography style={{fontSize: 'smaller'}}>
                                                {index.sif_msg}
                                            </Typography>
                                        </Grid>

                                        <Grid item>
                                            <Zoom overlayBgColorStart='rgba(73, 80, 87, 67)' overlayBgColorEnd='rgba(73, 80, 87, 67)' zoomMargin={100}>
                                                <img src={index.sif_image} alt={index.sif_image} className={classes.img} style={{maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: 200}}/>
                                            </Zoom>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>

                                </Paper>
                            </TimelineContent>

                        </TimelineItem>
                )
                })
            }
        </Timeline>
    )}
    export default index;
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get the problem. Can you please clarify what's wrong with the second item? Are you meaning with _text_ the _date_?

Comment: The second one have the text (TITLE and DESCRIPTION) to the left and image to the right. I always want the text near the center. (Where there is the PC icon). I would like to make the text alternates  each time. (text to the left, then text to the right, then text to the left ...) Don't pay attention to the date. Hope it's better :S

Comment: thx now I see :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [modulo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) to determine if we're on an even or odd iteration, and adjust accordingly. I've also set the title component as a variable so we don't have to duplicate it:

```
{result.map((index, i) => {
    
    let isEven = i % 2 === 0,
        titleComponent = (
            <Grid item>
                <Typography variant="h6" component="h1">
                    {index.sif_titre}
                </Typography>
                <Typography style={{fontSize: 'smaller'}}>
                    {index.sif_msg}
                </Typography>
            </Grid>
        );
    
    return (
        <TimelineItem className={classes.timelineStyle}>

            <TimelineOppositeContent>
                <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
                    {index.sif_date}
                </Typography>
            </TimelineOppositeContent>

            <TimelineSeparator>
                <TimelineDot className={classes.dot}>
                    <LaptopMacIcon/>
                </TimelineDot>
                <TimelineConnector />
            </TimelineSeparator>

            <TimelineContent>
                <Paper elevation={3} className={classes.paper}>

                    <Grid style={{display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'nowrap'}}>

                        {isEven && titleComponent}

                        <Grid item>
                            <Zoom overlayBgColorStart='rgba(73, 80, 87, 67)' overlayBgColorEnd='rgba(73, 80, 87, 67)' zoomMargin={100}>
                                <img src={index.sif_image} alt={index.sif_image} className={classes.img} style={{maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: 200}}/>
                            </Zoom>
                        </Grid>

                        {!isEven && titleComponent}

                    </Grid>

                </Paper>
            </TimelineContent>

        </TimelineItem>
    )
})}
```

Modulo example:
https://jsfiddle.net/q12yah85/

Comment: Somehow, after I tried your modification, the text is now invisible or gone :/

Comment: I would double check the titleComponent variable, and make sure everything is right with that. Let me know how that goes.

Comment: I double checked and isEven is always false, that's must be the problem

Comment: I've updated the code. Note that now in the map params there is (index, i), and the isEven uses i now.

Comment: The reason it was always false, is because your index is an object, not an integer. We need to get the actual integer index.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ! Sorry again for all your times buuut ... The result I get now is  weird : For a Card i got : Text - Image - Text(Duplicate) for all the Cards to the right. For all Cards in the left it's only the Image now. Now I think it's a problem of style.

Comment: Okay it work ! Didn't put the "!" at the second  {isEven && titleComponent}

Comment: @Quentin - Great, I'm glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with an `nth-child` selector in CSS and then toggle between your styles / flex direction.

Docs for the nth-child selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
  flex-directrion: row;
}

.parent:nth-child(2n+1){ /* or: :nth-child(odd) */
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="img">IMG</div>
  <div class="txt">txt</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="img">IMG</div>
  <div class="txt">txt</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="img">IMG</div>
  <div class="txt">txt</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="img">IMG</div>
  <div class="txt">txt</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Another fun part about the :nth-child psuedo selector is that you can actually just use :nth-child(odd) or :nth-child(even). :)

Comment: @wrxsti yes, totally overseen that. :)

Comment: extended my answer with the `odd` implementation.

Comment: Sorry for the long respond but i've tried your method (with 2n+1 AND odd) and it didn't work ? I see that the CSS parameters are applied when I inspect the page EXCEPT that the flex-direction: 'row' is not applied (grayed).

Comment: @Quentin can you please create a https://codepen.io/ and paste your rendered HTML and your CSS?

Comment: @yourbraineatsyou I've edited my post and added the full code of my page, maybe more easier than just the CSS and HTML ?

Comment: I think I got your problem: you are assigning the `:nth-child` selector to the wrong class. You have to apply it to the `TimelineItem` (the outer most parent element) and then apply the `flex-direction` to the corresponding child.

Comment: Hmmm, nop it's not <TimeLineItem>. If I put my selector at TimeLineItem it's everything that moves, (The dots, the PC icon, the dates ...) and it still only take the flex-direction: 'row-reverse' putting everything on the left

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237167/discussion-between-yourbraineatsyou-and-quentin).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const MuiTimelineItem = withStyles({
  alignAlternate: {
    "&:nth-child(even) .MuiTimelineItem-content": {
      direction: "rtl"
    }
  }
})(TimelineItem);
```